# Row sum in PIVOT query

Tags: oracle

Please Help me i am trying to create pivot but not success.

query

```
select 
t.g_no,
t.sz,
t.DT,
t.Qty
from gp123 t
```

Result

```
 4480   46  4/24/2017   30
 4480   42  4/24/2017   28
 4480   40  4/24/2017   37
 4480   44  4/24/2017   26
 4480   50  4/24/2017   17
 4480   48  4/24/2017   2
```

Required result

```
  Gate Pass No.   Date      40  42  44  46  48  50     Total
  4480           24-Apr-17  37  28  26  30  2   17       140
  4500           25-Apr-17  187 140 155 127 99  85       793
  4537           25-Apr-17  141 97  139 172 141 159      849
  4538           26-Apr-17  90  141 122 148 172 151      824
  4542           26-Apr-17  1   60  118 63  32  3        277
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SUM() OVER ()` analytic function to get the total and then use `PIVOT` to convert the rows to columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT g_no AS "Gate Pass No.",
                sz,
                DT AS "Date",
                Qty,
                SUM( qty ) OVER ( PARTITION BY g_no, DT ) AS Total
          FROM  gp123
       )
PIVOT  ( SUM( qty ) FOR sz IN ( 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50 ) )
```

Comment: Not a required Result        
Gate pass no. Date Total 40 42        44        46         48       50
4480       24-Apr-17         140 37  26       30      2  17

Comment: @m.khan's Sorry, your comment appears to be a list of columns and values and it is unclear what the point is you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

... or simply:

```
select g_no, dt, "40", "42", "44", "46", "48", "50",
       "40" + "42" + "44" + "46" + "48" + "50" total
  from gp123 t
  pivot (sum(qty) for sz in (40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50));
```

Comment: i want to put  select query in               like                                                     pivot (sum(qty) for itemsize in (select * from dual, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50));     please guide me